# A list in a class seems to be static?

Tags: python, list, class, static, construction

In a Python class I wrote the following method:

```
class user():
    address_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.address_list.append("a")
```

When I use it as this:

```
ur1 = user()
ur1.address_list.append("b")
ur2 = user()
ur2.address_list.append("c")
ur2.address_list.append("d")

print("user1's address: ", len(ur1.address_list))
print("user2's address: ", len(ur2.address_list))
```

The output was:

```
user1's address: 5
user2's address: 5
```

But my expectation was:

```
user1's address: 2   #a, b
user2's address: 3   #a,c,d
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You indentation is wrong. Try indenting address_list and init to be in the same block as the class.

Comment: All your `user` instances share a single `address_list`.  Move `self.address_list = []` to the `__init__`

Comment: Yes, it is static, it's a class attribute, not an instance attribute.

Comment: Do print the user's address together, you'll see the problem. `__init__` is appending 'a' twice thus the 5.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes. move the self.address_list = [] into the constuctor is ok. Thanks.